# How to implement XOR operation for Hexadecimal values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xor, hex

I followed this fiddle     [jsfiddle.net/4m6d3/](http://jsfiddle.net/4m6d3/)      to do Xor Operation ,if i enter number it works but when I enter Hexadecimal then it is displaying as NAN.
Please Suggest How to do XOR Operation for hexadecimal values in JavaScript.

```
function bitCalc(num1, num2, mode) {
    var arr1 = getPaddedArray(num1, num2.length),
    arr2 = getPaddedArray(num2, num1.length);
    console.log(arr1)
    console.log(arr2)

    var res = arr1.map(function(bit1,i) {
        bit1 = parseInt(bit1,10);
        var bit2 = parseInt(arr2[i],10);
        switch (mode) {
            case "and":
                return Math.floor((bit1+bit2)/2);
            case "or":
                return Math.ceil((bit1+bit2)/2);
            case "xor": 
                return Math.abs(bit1-bit2);
        }
    });
    return res.join("");
}

function getPaddedArray(str, length) {
    var arr = str.split("");
    if (arr.length < length) {
        return Array(length + 1 - arr.length).join(0).split("").concat(arr);
    } else return arr;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to add additional field to specify base. You can't tell if a string is hexadecimal or decimal number from the string itself. For example consider '10' is it 16 or 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    bit1 = parseInt("0x"+bit1,16);
    var bit2 = parseInt("0x"+arr2[i],16);
```

instead of

```
    bit1 = parseInt(bit1,10);
    var bit2 = parseInt(arr2[i],10);
```

See this working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4m6d3/3/

Comment: Thanks for Your response,if i need to do basic xor operations like (101FFC ^ 100DCA) how i can achieve

Comment: convert the answer to hexadecimal by using **HexAns = yourNumber.toString(16);**